# Выбирать каждый третий и четвертый элемент CSS

Tags: html, css

У меня есть колонка с множеством блоков по 50% ширины (по 2 в ряд).

Мне нужно поменять цвет в каждом 3 и 4 блоках.

Вот пример:

```css
.row {
width: 400px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row div {
width: 48%;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row div:nth-child(3n) {

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Вот скрин блоков, к которым нужно получить доступ через nth-child.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.row {
width: 400px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row div {
width: 48%;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row div:nth-child(4n+3), .row div:nth-child(4n) {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```